# How to setup a .local Wifi hostname to SSH in a Linux system?

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, hostname

I SSH to my Raspberry Pi's wifi via `ssh raspberrypi.local`, simply done by adding the following code in a file named `wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
 ssid="Welcome Home"
 psk="Thanhlich267"
 priority=1
}
```

I am trying to learn to do the same thing with other Linux Embedded system (Google Coral Board, BeagleBone), but I did not know how to accomplish this. Can someone please advise me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wpa_supplicant.conf` is just for configuring the WiFi network connectivity: it has nothing to do with making the `.local` hostname available. That part is done by the `avahi-daemon` service, which is enabled by default on RasPis. It uses the [multicast DNS, or mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) protocol to announce its name and IP to other systems on the same network segment (only).

Normally, the default configuration of `avahi-daemon` should be enough to make the system findable in the network as `<hostname>.local`. Just make sure that the service is installed and started on your other embedded systems.

Unfortunately, it looks like the [Mendel Linux for Google Coral Board](https://coral.googlesource.com/docs/+/refs/heads/master/ReadMe.md) might be more stripped-down and so less user-friendly than the Raspbian that is commonly used on RasPis.

BeagleBoards may have originally been delivered with the [Ångstrom distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) but currently [seem to have Debian-based images available for them](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images) - which are you using?

Comment: Your information is exactly what I am looking for. I use Google Coral Development Board running Mendel Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your RPi has its hostname set by default to `raspberrypi`. "Zero Config Networking"/`avahi` adds the `.local` suffix. If you look in `/etc/hostname` on your RPi you should see this - you may change the default to something else if you wish.

My point is this: Have you checked your other OS's to see if they have the file `/etc/hostname`? If so, edit the file & add the hostname. If not, try searching for something like "set hostname Google Coral Board / BeagleBone".

Comment: Yes. I use Google Development Board, and the Mendel Linux already has the ```daemon-avahi``` setup with ```hostname``` under ```/etc/hostname```. I just have to change it to what I need.